# Can't find second partition on encrypted drive with two partitions

Tags: windows-7, encryption, mount, truecrypt

I have a drive with two partitions, a system partition (Windows 7) and a partition just for data. Both are encrypted with the same password.

I didn't had any problems, but yesterday my laptop gets broken. Now, I'm trying to connect the drive via USB to a new laptop and read it.

The problem is, that I only see the system partition, not the one with my data. When I click on "Select Device", I can see my drive as "Harddisk 1" with 300 gb. But I only see a single partition "Partition1" with 117 gb. I'm unable to find the second one. It's not a hidden partition.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
Or is it a problem with windows? It seems like windows is only recognizing the first partition...

Comment: How exactly did your laptop break?

Comment: the error code says that the cpu or motherbord is broken. but the drive seems to be ok. i can read the first partition with no problems.